# MariaDB does not do Execute Insert in Procedure

Tags: mysql, insert, mariadb, procedure, execute

I am using MySQL -actually MariaDB from PHPMyAdmin- and trying to write an insert inside a stored procedure and for obvious (security) reasons it is not allowed.

I tried to change the permissions using the GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE statement.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE test.putDataInFull TO 'root'@'localhost'
```

I have really hit a wall here, any ideas?

edit:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE putDataInFull (IN matchid INT(11))
BEGIN
  DECLARE koula int(11);
  DECLARE c     varchar(255);
  SET @koula = matchid;
  SET @c := concat('insert into log (match_id, comment) values (?,\'inPUtDataWeTrtust\');');

  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
       BEGIN
         SELECT CONCAT(@c, ' is not valid');
       END;
  PREPARE stmt FROM @c;
  EXECUTE stmt USING @koula;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

p.s. this is not a production project, just fun, so I really do not care about security.

Comment: Welcome at Stackoverflow. Can you show us the error message?

Comment: Thank Charlie, I do not get any errors at all, I tried to put an SQLEXCEPTΙΟΝ in the procedure and then got an error because of the exception handling ...

Comment: Can you show us your code in the stored procedure?

Comment: sure thing,
give me a a sec to find out how to make it s code :-)

Comment: May in your question with code formatting :-)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

You can create an insert with your variables. It is not necessary to create a magic string. Here you get an other example of [an other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43474546/mariadb-insert-stored-procedure-with-parameter):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE  PROCEDURE ADD_WITHDRAWAL_A(IN withdrawalcode_p VARCHAR(25), IN id_p VARCHAR(8), IN amount_p VARCHAR(12), IN datewithdrawn_p VARCHAR(35), IN approved_p VARCHAR(8))
BEGIN

     START TRANSACTION;

     INSERT INTO Withdrawals(WithdrawalCode, IDD, Amount, DateWithdrawn, Approved) 
     VALUES (withdrawalcode_p, id_p, amount_p, datewithdrawn_p, approved_p);

     UPDATE account SET AccountBalance = AccountBalance - amount_p WHERE IDD = id_p LIMIT 1;

     COMMIT;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: what I seek is to pass the name of the field as parameter ...
so unfortunately this is not the case (and the START TRANSACTION will not do the trick ...